# Is unit testing "order by id" possible?

Tags: sql, postgresql, unit-testing

Imagine you have the following schema and data:

```
create table test (
  id serial primary key,
  x integer not null,
  y integer not null
);

insert into test (x, y) values (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8);
```

If I wanted to get the values of `test` in inserted order, I can use:

```
select * from test order by id;
```

I want to write a unit test that can *fail* if the `order by id` is not present (e.g. following [red/green/refactor](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/12/17/TheCyclesOfTDD.html)).

My *failing* test would:

1. Insert some data into `test`.
2. Run the method that calls `select * from test` and returns the data (changing this to `select * from test order by id` should make the test pass).
3. Verify that the returned data of the method is in the same order that iteration occurred in #1 (aka it should be ordered by `id`).

However, this test has the possibility of returning false-positives (and this is usually the case without any indexes on the table). The [order of a query without `order by` is unspecified](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-order.html#QUERIES-ORDER).

One solution I've thought of is hacking around with the `id`'s sequence so that the `id` gets generated in an odd order... but that feels like a hack just to make this test possible.

**EDIT:** Alright, there seems to be some confusion. I know that order is not guaranteed without an `order by` (I even quoted to docs). I can not change the table/view that is queried. I am fixing a bug in a method that *today* does not use `order by id`. However, we know that this method *should* use `order by id`. Therefore, I need to change the code to use `order by id`. Before I do this, I want to write a unit test that reproduces this bug (the results of the method are not sorted by `id`). It so happens that Postgres is returning the data sorted by `id` since, I guess, the data is coming off disk in the order it was inserted. This is creating a false-positive in the test: it is *passing* when it should be failing. I want to eliminate false-positives: it should reliably fail before I fix the bug.

Comment: you can just check if any next id is less than the previous one. Since sequence generation is always increasing order.

Comment: You *can fudge this* in all sorts of ways.  Principally by attempting to manipulate the order the database engine writes the rows to disk, and then relying on the notion that the rows are ***likely*** to come back in that order if no `ORDER BY` is used.  ***But it is still not guaranteed behaviour***.  When the manual says `If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified order.`, it means it.  It will be an indeterminate order, and you can do nothing about that with 100% reliability.  The only *guaranteed* method to control the order of the results is with the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Your step 3 is wrong. You wouldn't verify it's in the same order it's inserted. You'd verify it's in ID order. You *happened* to insert them in ID order, but a database is never guaranteed to return you rows in the order they were inserted.

Comment: @Schwern see my edits. The steps were for the *failing* test and what is expected. The method would be changed to call `select * from test order by id` to make the test pass.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky Databases have no default sorting. You cannot guarantee it will come back in the same order it was inserted. You can only continue to perturb the data until a `select` with no `order by` comes back out of order. Even then there's no guarantee the same query with no `order by` will come out the same way twice.

Comment: @Schwern Yes, I completely understand that. That's the point of this question: make a test that fails using *no* `order by id` but adding `order by id` makes the test fail.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky Yes, and your step 3 is wrong. `select * from test` has no order to verify. Instead, you want to verify that it isn't in ID order. This isn't a test, you're setting up the environment for your test to reduce the chance of a false positive. The test is running the method and checking it returns results in order.

Comment: @Schwern No, you're wrong. I'm inserting values in *an order* (e.g. in a loop) and I want to verify that the method call returns the data *in that same order*. I've updated the question with an edit to provide more clarity.

Comment: @MatBailie So, the answer to the question is: there is no reliable way to actually test this even with fudging the sequence (like I said in the question)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135122/discussion-between-schwern-and-thecloudlesssky).

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky Long story short, the confusion is this: *3. Verify that the returned data of the method is in the same order it was inserted in #1.* Change that to *3. Verify that the returned data of the method is in ID order* and you'll stop poking the SQL dragons.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' No, they're testing whether the devs can remember to specify an ordering on their queries, or if they're accidentally relying on happenstance ordering.

Comment: @Schwern Or in the actual case, to fix a bug (and create a reliable failing test that proves why the fix was made).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *However, this test has the possibility of returning false-positives (and this is usually the case without any indexes on the table).*

Then add some indexes on the table! Presumably you're using your own little database created for this instance of the unit test that's going to be blown away, do whatever you like with it. Indexes don't change the guaranteed result from queries, and without an `order by` order is not guaranteed, just their performance. So this is a safe alteration to the environment.

---

> *One solution I've thought of is hacking around with the id's sequence so that the id gets generated in an odd order... but that feels like a hack just to make this test possible.*

Unit testing often bends the normal Best Practices rules. In this case it's in service of setting up your test data just so to avoid a false positive. This is no different than creating a test file just so to test for a rare bug in a method. While this makes the test [glassbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing) because its peeking under the hood at the storage mechanism, that's a valid unit testing technique for something this detailed.

Start from where the sequence is at.

```
select last_value from test_id_seq;
```

Then go from there (let's say it's 8).

```
insert into test (id, x, y) values (10, 1, 2), (12, 3, 4), (11, 5, 6), (9, 7, 8);
```

This will confuse the sequence and the next few inserts will fail, so you have to make sure to put it back on track by restarting the sequence.

```
alter sequence test_id_seq restart with 12;
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't safe if other processes are simultaneously talking to the same database, but this shouldn't matter in a unit test. Blow the table away at the end of the test.

Similarly, try deleting some rows and then inserting more.

---

Because there is ***no guaranteed order of results without an `order by`*** even perturbing the data in this way isn't guaranteed to work. Instead, iterate over various techniques until you get the data back out of order. Something like this:

```
def test_ordering
    while `select * from test` is ordered by id
        if we've tried too may times
            warn and go ahead anyway
        end

        perturb the data in test
    end

    assert obj.method is in id order
end
```

This is the best you can do. At a certain point you have to cut your losses.

Comment: This is the test (in pseudo code): http://pastebin.com/raw/PaW1CXmk

I've clarified #3. You're right that because order is never guaranteed it's impossible even if we fake the ids with the sequence (like you and I suggested). So, the test is not reliable (and can either be removed or left with a comment warning that it can have false positives).

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky A test that is vulnerable to false positives should most definitely be left in; a false positive is better than no test at all, it can still catch negatives. And while you cannot guarantee `select * from test` will be out of order, you can stack the deck in your favor. Remember, the point of testing is not to be perfect, testing can never verify there are no bugs and [you never have enough time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost), but to be practical. Also, since you're not inserting via `some_thing`, `some_thing` ***cannot know the order you inserted them***.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky I keep banging on about this because your unit test assumes things about the table structure. For example, what if the table was using UUIDs for primary keys? Then ID order is not insertion order. What you need to do is verify that `data` matches `select * from test order by id`. What you ***really*** need to do is look at the docs for `get_points`, check what it's documented to do, see that makes sense, and test that. If it's documented to be "in insertion order" meaning the order they were put into the database, that's not good, and the docs need to change.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot tell from a query result whether the query contains an `ORDER BY` or not.**

A query is only guaranteed to return rows in a particular order when you specify this order in `ORDER BY`. So your initial assumption is wrong and there is no way to look at a query's result and determine from it whether an `ORDER BY` was applied or not. The `ORDER BY` might be missing and the correct row order mere coincidence.

Even if you wanted to trick this and select from a sorted view instead, this would not help. If you created a view on, say, `select * from test order by id desc` and then check whether a query on this view returned the rows *asccending*, this would mean nothing, because

```
select * from test_view;
```

would essentially be

```
select * from (select * from test order by id desc);
```

so you'd select from a derived table, which itself again is an unordered set of data by definition (i.e. the `ORDER BY` clause within has no guaranteed effect on the results).

Comment: I'd like to amend that this doesn't mean you shouldn't try to eliminate false positives, but focus on reducing their probability. At a certain point there's more probable bugs to focus on; [opportunity cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost) should always be on your mind when doing QA.

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. I completely know that there is no way to know the order of the method if it used `order by`. The problem is that the order that the method returns should be the same order that the insert was performed. I can't change which table/view is queried in the SQL. I need a failing test *without* using `order by`.